# check the number to see if it repeats, and if so, add another value, Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I add +100 to the number, but I have to give the condition that +200 is added for each repeated number and it will change with each iteration
Thus, if the number 1 is repeated a second time, it does not add +100 but +200, and when the third, +300, etc.

Example:
My output

```
1  2  3 
-101 -201 -301
-102 -202 -302
-103 -203 -303
2  1  3 
-102 -202 -302
-101 -201 -301
-103 -203 -303
```

I need:
this is how I would need it to work

```
1  2  3 
-101 -201 -301
-102 -202 -302
-103 -203 -303
2  1  3 
-202 -402 -602
-201 -401 -601
-203 -403 -603
1  3  2 
-301 -601 -901
-303 -603 -903
-302 -602 -902
```

part of the code where I work with it

```
 c1=np.array(c1)
c1=np.array([c1]*3)

c1=np.transpose(c1)
left=c1+100*np.ones((1,1))*((1,2,3))
left=left*-1
```

my all code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import re


f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
#sys.stdout = open("results.txt", "w")
for i in list(lines):
     if i[0] != '<' and i[0] != '>' and i[0] != '=':
        p = str(' '.join(i.split()))
        print(p)
        
     else:
        w = i[3:]
        w = ', '.join(w.split())
        #print(w)
        y = i[2]
        y=int(y)+1
        #print(y)
        c=np.array([w])
        c1 = [int(i) for i in c[0].replace(" ", "").split(",")]
        c1=np.array(c1)
        c1=np.array([c1]*3)

        c1=np.transpose(c1)
        left=c1+300*np.ones((1,1))*((1,2,3))
        left=left*-1
        
        left=str(left).replace("[",'')
        left=str(left).replace("]",'')
        left=str(left).replace(".",'')
        left=str(left).replace("\n ",'\n')
             
        
        right=str(c1).replace("[",'')
        right=str(right).replace("]",'')
        right=str(right).replace(".",'')
        right=str(right).replace("\n ",'\n')
        get=re.findall(r'\w+ ', right)
        get = list(dict.fromkeys(get))      
        get=str(get).replace("[",'')
        get=str(get).replace("]",'')
        get=str(get).replace("'",'')
        get=str(get).replace(",",'')
        print(get)
        print(left)
        print(*(f' {i} 0\n'.join(s.split() + ['']) for s, i in zip(left.splitlines(),get.split())), sep="")
```

demofile.txt

```
<=1 1 2 3 
<=1 2 1 3
<=1 1 3 2
```

Comment: So when the number occurs first time you're going to add +100, second time +200 etc.?  Because it doesn't make sense for your example output.

Comment: exactly as you wrote, if, for example, the number 3 occurs +500 five times

Comment: And where do you wanna store that +500 value?

Comment: so i work with it in the code where left = c1 + 100 * np.ones ((1,1)) * ((1,2,3)) so to some variable in that formula instead of +100, if I'm correct you understood

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand. Why is the array in 3x3 shape?

Comment: Also code that you have posted isn't working. Please try to provide working code that outputs your example output. So I can work from there.

Comment: 3x3 because for those numbers 1,2,3 I create auxiliary variables and for each number there are 3 variables. These variables must not be repeated, so I want to put the condition there. Of course, I'll edit the question and paste all my code there